# Java - compareTo and operators

Tags: java, operators, comparable, compareto

If I have a class `Person` that implements `Comparable` (compares `personA.height` to `personB.height`, for example), is it possible to use

```
    personA < personB
```

as a substitute for

```
    personA.compareTo(personB) == -1?
```

Are there any issues in doing this or do I need to overload operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no operator overloading in Java. You probably come from a C++ background.

You have to use the `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 15):

No, it isn't possible to use `personA < personB` as a substitute. And you can't overload operators in Java.

Also, I'd recommend changing

```
personA.compareTo(personB) == -1
```

to

```
personA.compareTo(personB) < 0
```

What you have now probably works for your class. However, the contract on [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) is that it returns *a negative value* when `personA` is less than `personB`. That negative value doesn't have to be -1, and your code might break if used with a different class. It could also break if someone were to change your class's `compareTo()` method to a different -- but still compliant -- implementation.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible, no; and Java doesn't support operator overloading (besides the built-in overloads).

By the way, instead of writing `== -1`, you should write `< 0`. `compareTo` is just required to return a negative/zero/positive value, not specifically -1/0/1.

Answer (score 2):

It is not posible, java does not give you operator overload.
But a more OO option is to add a method inside person

```
public boolean isTallerThan(Person anotherPerson){
    return this.compareTo(anotherPerson) > 0;
}
```

so instead of writing

```
if(personA.compareTo(personB) > 0){

}
```

you can write

```
if(personA.isTallerThan(personB)){

}
```

IMHO it is more readable because it hides details and it is expressed in domain language rather than java specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have operator overloading<sup>1</sup>, so, yes, there's an issue: this is not possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are, of course, a few overloadings built in: the `+` operator works on integral types, floating-point types, and on `String`s. But you can't define your own.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "<" won't compile when applied to objects. Also, be careful of your test:

```
personA.compareTo(personB)==-1
```

The API docs merely say that compareTo() returns a negative integer when the object is less than the specified object, which won't necessarily be -1. Use

```
personA.compareTo(personB) < 0
```

instead.