# Compare objects of other class

Tags: java, comparable

I'm having `trouble comparing objects of another class`, how should I proceed?
I made a tasty example, hopefully the code should be self-explanatory.

cake.java:

```
public class Cake implements Comparable<Cake> {

  private final int tastyness;

  public Cake(tastyness) {
    this.tastyness = tastyness;
  }

  public int compareTo(Cake other) {
    return this.tastyness - other.tastyness;
  }
}
```

makeBestDinner.java:

```
public class makeBestDinner {

  List<Cake> cakes = new ArrayList<cake>();
  // Make a whole lot of cakes here
  if (cakes[0] > cakes[1]) {
    System.out.println("The first cake tastes better than the second");
  }

  // Do the same for beverages
}
```

Comment: +1 for the food example. -1 for making me hungry :\

Comment: Why didn't you use `compareTo` method when you have already overridden it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946071/java-compareto-and-operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Java does not support operator overloading hence following will not
  work.

> ```
>   if (cakes[0] > cakes[1]) {
> ```

instead, you should

```
if (cakes.get(0).compareTo(cakes.get(1)) > 0) {
```

- Also to get elements from list we need to call `list.get(index)` not

> list[index]

So following code will not work.

```
List<Cake> cakes = new ArrayList<cake>();
// Make a whole lot of cakes here
if (cakes[0] > cakes[1]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(cakes.get(0).compareTo(cakes.get(1)) > 0) {
    System.out.println("The first cake tastes better than the second");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use `if (cakes[0].compareTo( cakes[1]))>0)` instead

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked! However, I was under the impression that the '<' operator should work when a compareTo method is defined? When trying to use '<', I get: **The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s)  oving9.SokobanResult, oving9.SokobanResult**
even though Comparable<SokobanResult> is implemented in oving9.SokobanResult.

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
if (cakes.get(0).compareTo(cakes.get(1)) > 0) {
    System.out.println("The first cake tastes better than the second");
}
```

and read the [Comparable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Answer (score 0):

`if (cakes[0] > cakes[1])...`

Is there not a problem here?
As people have said, you should use `if(cakes[0].compareTo(cakes[1]) > 0)`
Well I would say that BUT you're using an ArrayList. Can you really get elements by typing listname[elementnumber]? I thought you have to use listname.get(elementnumber).